# Suggest or a request form on a Wordpress site, how automatically know from which user?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce

about the background: so we are making a WP site, which uses WooCommerce and FooEvents. FooEvents is a plugin for WooCommerce which lets us list events and make the tickets. We also installed a plugin for Members called WooCommerce Memberships.

All in all we want to have a form on our site where people can suggest their event. We want it to be the easiest can be. Maybe its a dumb question but:

How can we automatically know which user filled out the form and sent it to us? We would like to avoid any Email or username entries.

Can I use a contact form 7? Or is there any free alternative in the best case, otherwise paid.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

If your users have already an account on your website and they are logged in, here you have the possibility to populate automatically the fields Name and Email with Contact Form 7:

https://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/

Comment: Thanks! I'ts an option. But isn't there any possibility of the happening in the background without them seeing these fields? Or should I just put them on "display:none"?

Comment: You're welcome Daniel. I thought about that and I see your point. It seems not an option with Contact Form 7, but you can try the "display: none;". It's not the best solution, but it should work fine.